# Transferring int array through intent-Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I am trying to pass an int array through an Intent to another Activity in Android

On the first side I have :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,StatsPage.class);
    intent.putExtra(STATISTICS,NUMBERS_ROLLED);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On the other side I have:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int[] arrayOfNums = extras.getIntArray("STATISTICS");
```

This code keeps crashing on me. 
Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: What is the type of STATISTICS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your extras like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,StatsPage.class);
intent.putExtra("STATISTICS", NUMBERS_ROLLED);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your source activity, make sure your key `STATISTICS` is defined as a `public static final` *constant*. In your destination activity, you can then refer to it as

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] arrayOfNums = extras.getIntArray(SourceActivity.STATISTICS);
```

This makes sure that you don't misspell the key and run into `NullPointerException` when the extra is not found due to a key name mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray(SourceActivity.STATISTICS);
```